# Subtract four weeks from current time stamp

Tags: java

```
long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
String dateStr = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.0Z'").format(new java.util.Date(epoch * 1000));
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get the time stamp of 4 weeks from the current one? I'm working on payroll testing.

Answer (score 5):

Subtract the number of milliseconds in 4 weeks from the current time.

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long fourWeeksAgo = now - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 28;
```

Comment: While this might work in this particular case, you really should be using a `Calendar`to muck with time/date

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm not sure why. But the subtraction worked as plus.

Comment: No need to roll your own date-time handling. Use the modern *java.time* classes instead.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.Calendar` provides a means of manipulating dates so that code is readable:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -4);
long fourWeeksAgo = calendar.getTime().getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(java.util.Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -4);
```